# How should I select items from a list based on keyword when each item might have several keywords (or phrases)

Tags: php, arrays, search

I started out like this, but decided it would be way too long winded if I get more items.

```
$keyword=getKeyword();

switch (true)
  {
    case $keyword=='special product':
    $keyword_custom_items[]='SPECIAL';
    break;

    case ($keyword=='other special' || $keyword=='other specials' || $keyword=='more specials'):
    $keyword_custom_items[]='EXTRA-SPECIAL';
    break;

    default:
    break;
  }

// handle custom items if $keyword_custom_items is set.
```

Besides needing to duplicate myself for plural words, This does not allow for near matches. 
What is a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: not clear to me, but maybe `in_array()`

Comment: I'm looking for a fulltext search and it looks like I need to work with array_filter and a callback function. I'll tweak on that for a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
$keyword_to_item=array(
'blender bottles'=>'MIX-IT',
'shaker bottles'=>'MIX-IT',
'shaker cups'=>'MIX-IT',
'mixer bottles'=>'MIX-IT',
'protein mixer'=>'MIX-IT',
'protein shaker'=>'MIX-IT',
);

if(!function_exists(keyword_search)){ //THIS IS IN A LOOP, SO MAKE SURE WE DO NOT REDECLARE
function keyword_search($val)
  {
    global $promotional;
    $lc_keyword=strtolower($promotional);
    similar_text($lc_keyword,$val,$similarity);
    return $similarity > 70;
  }
}
$found=array_filter(array_keys($keyword_to_item),"keyword_search");

$found=array_values($found);
foreach((array)$keyword_to_item[$found[0]] as $item)
  {
    //DO STUFF
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression matching.
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

or if you're just switching several cases of $keyword, you can:

```
switch ($keyword) {
    case "special product":
       $keyword_custom_items[]='SPECIAL';
       break;
    case "other special":
    case "other specials":
    case "more specials":
       $keyword_custom_items[]='EXTRA-SPECIAL';
       break;
    default:
       $keyword_custom_items[]='NONE';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strpos to search for a string within a string. While it's still going to be pretty lengthy, it would help your system find "special" if the user writes "specials".

```
if (strpos($keyword, 'special') !== false)
   {$keyword_custom_items[]='SPECIAL';}
```